# python execute program with access to specific functions

Tags: python

I want to execute a program from the user. It should be able to call functions from the main program that i allow and that can change variables in the main program but it shouldn't be able to change variables in the main program without these allowed functions.

main program:

```
import traceback

def forward():
  if pos < 100:
    pos += 1
    return True
  else:
    return False

def private():
  print "I'm private!"

pos = 0


print(pos)

path = input("Enter the path to your program: ")
try:
  program = open(path)
  code = compile(program.read(), path, "exec")
  # exec code in a way that allows the code to use the forward function
except:
  traceback.print_exc()
finally:
  program.close()

print(pos)
```

entering the path to a file with the content

```
if forward():
  print("walked forward")
else:
  print("couldn't walk forward")
```

should give the output

```
0
walked forward
1
```

entering the path to a file with the content

```
pos = 10 # should be a local variable for the users program
```

should give the output

```
0
0
```

entering the path to a file with the content

```
private()
```

should give the exception

```
NameError: name 'private' is not defined
```

entering the path to a file with the content

```
pos += 5
```

should give the exception

```
NameError: name 'pos' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the exec function you can pass a dictionary that will be used as the namespace to execute the code in. This protects against accidental misuse of private functions and variables. However, this is by no means secure. A determined person will still be able to get access to `private` and `pos`.

```
exec(code, {"forward": forward})
```

To demonstrate that the globals a function refers to are always the globals of the module it was defined in.

```
value = 0
def getter():
    return value
def setter(new_value):
    global value
    value = new_value
source = """
assert getter() == 0, "expected 0, but got {}".format(getter())
setter(1)
value = -1
assert getter() == 1, "expected 1, but got {}".format(getter())
"""
try:
    exec(source) # using this modules globals
except AssertionError as e:
    print("executed source, but it raised an AssertionError")
    print(e)
else:
    assert value == -1
    print("executed source, but it modified our value")
value = 0 # reset value
exec(source, {"getter": getter, "setter": setter}) # no assertion error
assert value == 0
print("executed source, and it did not modify our value")
```

Comment: this will just copy the function to the new enviroment. the function will try to change pos in the new environment but because their is no variable called pos in the new environment it will cause an error. how would be the way to get access to private and pos?

Comment: Nope. Functions defined in a given module will always use the globals of that module, rather than any module they are moved to.

Comment: ah i see, i need the global statement to make this work